# How do I set a in discord.py a command without Prefix only with certain word

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So, I'am building a discord bot for my private server with python. I want it to reply to a message when a specific message is written for example a person would write "Hi!" and the bot would respond "Hi!". I tried the code `@bot.event async def on_message(Hi!): await message.send("Hello!")` but it doesn't work. The error is "name 'bot' is not defined". Can any of you help? Here is my whole code **NOTE: IT'S IN LITHUANIAN LANGUAGE AND IT'S AMONG US THEMED**
```import discord
import random

````
from discord.ext import commands

from random import choice



client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '/', help_command=None)

status = ['Žudau crewmates', 'Apsimetinėju :eyes:', 'Prižiūriu https://discord.gg/FNsBtsA']

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Imposteris pasiruošęs.')
    
@client.command()
async def komandos(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'/ping - parodo jūsų interneto greitį, /patarimas - botas duoda patarimą Among Us žaidimui, /meme - Duoda kokį nors among us meme.')

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Pong! {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms')

@client.command()
async def patarimas(ctx):
    choices = ["Jei nori būti imposter, pasirink orandžinę spalvą. Ši spalva turi netgi 15.48% tapti imposter. Mažiausiai šansų turintis tėra violetinis. Jis turi tik 3.8%, kad tapti imposter.", "Jei nori kažką nužudyti nueik į admin, susirask tolimiausia nuo electrical, uždaryk savo auką su durimis, išjunk šviesas. Taip gausi kill'ą.", "Jei esi crewmate, niekuo nepasitikėk nebengi žmogus padarė visual task'ą (nesvarbu ar bar pakilo ar ne). Jei esi sus, sakyk, kad turi visual task'ą (jeigu aišku tokį turi).", "Jeigu matai žmogų kuris daro cardswipe, o tu jo neturi, jis bus imposteris. Tai common task'as, jį gali turėti visi arba niekas.", "Pati saugiausia vieta The Skeld žemelapyje yra communications. Ten retai kas užeina. O Polus saugiausia vieta pats startas. Mira HQ saugiausia vieta yra communications "]
    ranpatarimas = random.choice(choices)
    await ctx.send(ranpatarimas)

@client.command()
async def meme(ctx):
    choices = ["https://imgur.com/a/MvYabuk", "https://imgur.com/a/cKEp545", "https://imgur.com/a/5D4XVLl", "https://imgur.com/a/6IioFXt", "https://imgur.com/a/KdVz4WE", "https://imgur.com/a/BlLPvvc", "https://imgur.com/a/aKEMcfO", "https://imgur.com/a/e7Mnu9t", "https://imgur.com/a/sVfVodl", "https://imgur.com/a/F9Zz4A0", "https://imgur.com/a/vbCDxww", "https://imgur.com/a/3K0AHR3"]
    ranmeme = random.choice(choices)
    await ctx.send(ranmeme)

@bot.event
async def on_message(mirk):
    await message.send("NE! Mano mačas dar nesibaigė, o impostorium aš vis dar esu. Palauk prašau kol visus išžudysiu arba bent jau kai būsiu išvoteintas :slight_frown:)")

client.run(<TOKEN>)```
````

Comment: Change your token now.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple code just to get the idea.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:  # skip bot messages
        return

    # write all possible words in lower case. 
    if message.content.lower() in ['hey', 'hi', 'hello']:
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

    await bot.process_commands(message)  # to allow other commands
```

[Refrance](https://github.com/GreatTaku/Discord-Bot-Examples/blob/master/async/on_message.py)  but not for a bot instead a client it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your current solution will respond to every message sent to your server or to your bot dm's, no matter what's the content of it. You can simply check for it.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.lower() == 'hi!':
        await message.channel.send('Hi there')
 
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

And change your token, [**now**](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

Reference:

- [message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message)

EDIT:

Answering your comment, here's how to check if any word is in the message content

```py
if any(word in message.content.lower() for word in ['hi', 'hello!']):
    await message.channel.send('Hi there')

# or

if message.content.lower().startswith(['hi', 'hello!']):
    await message.channel.send('Hi there')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I really appreaciate it, tho I don't understand how to add multiple words like:
`if message.content.lower()== 'hi', 'hello!':`
and they would have the same answer. Is that possible somehow? I tried but it didn't work :/

Comment: Check the edit, also remember to accept the answer if it helped.